# Как из C# удалить переход на другой лист в Word?

Tags: c#, ms-word, doc

Соединяю несколько .docx документов в один. Как удалить переходы на другой лист?

Merge делаю так:

```
var result = new DocumentCore();
        foreach (var name in answers)
        {
            var item = DocumentCore.Load(name);
            SautinSoft.Document.Section section = item.Sections.FirstOrDefault();
            if (section != null)
                section.PageSetup.SectionStart = SectionStart.Continuous;
            result.Content.End.Insert(item.Content);
            result.Content.End.Insert("\n\n");
        }
        result.Save(path);
```

[image: Пример]

Comment: очень похоже что вы добавляете страницы одного документа в другой, а вам нужно добавить содержимое страниц, попробуйте получить содержимое страниц и добавить их в документ!

Comment: Кажеться, я добавляю содержимое здесь:
result.Content.End.Insert(item.Content);
Но проблема даже не в этом, мне бы просто узнать как удалить сам переход на другой лист. Вручную можна зайти в конец листа и нажать клавишу Delete, но вот програмно незнаю.

Comment: Добавьте в теги, какую именно библиотеку используете.

Comment: Я на самом деле пытался разными, конкретно в примере SautinSoft, мне главное удалить эти пустые переходы.